# How to write a query to get result in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have two mysql tables posts and follow where follow contain followid,from_user_id,to_user_id,date,status and post contain title,description,createdby,createdtime
I want to write a query to get latest added post which is posted by users who is following to a particular user. That means just our facebook page, to get post that our friends post to our page.Can any one help immediately.

Comment: With your current database structure, not possible

Comment: How is anyone supposed to digest your table structure out of paragraph format? We shouldn't have to work that hard to visualize your issue. read this yourself as if you were going to answer it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I changed a little bit your schema to look like this :

**follow table**

```
+------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field            | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| user_id          | int(11)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| followin_user_id | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| date             | datetime | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| status           | bit(1)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

**posts table**

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| post_id     | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| description | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| createdby   | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| createdtime | timestamp    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

lets populate some dummy data in both tables posts and follow like this

```
+---------+-------------+-----------------------------+-----------+---------------------+
| post_id | title       | description                 | createdby | createdtime         |
+---------+-------------+-----------------------------+-----------+---------------------+
|       1 | hello       | the sun is shiningtoday lol |         2 | 2015-07-18 01:05:46 |
|       2 | hello again | its night now               |         2 | 2015-07-18 01:06:23 |
|       3 | wow         | just wow                    |         1 | 2015-07-11 01:06:55 |
|       4 | yeah        | hi there                    |         3 | 2015-07-18 01:37:48 |
|       5 | yeah2       | hithere for the 2nd time    |         3 | 2015-07-18 01:40:05 |
+---------+-------------+-----------------------------+-----------+---------------------+

+---------+------------------+------+--------+
| user_id | followin_user_id | date | status |
+---------+------------------+------+--------+
|       1 | NULL             | NULL | NULL   |
|       2 |                1 | NULL | NULL   |
|       3 |                1 | NULL | NULL   |
|       4 |                2 | NULL | NULL   |
|       5 |                2 | NULL | NULL   |
+---------+------------------+------+--------+
```

if you are using innodb then you can create a foreign key like this

```
ALTER TABLE `posts` ADD CONSTRAINT `posts_ibfk` FOREIGN KEY (`createdby`) REFERENCES `follow` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

if not using innodb then nevermind the last command :p

now to get the last post of the user that follows another user  use the following query

```
$qry = $this->db->query('
SELECT
*
FROM
posts
INNER JOIN follow ON posts.createdby = follow.user_id
WHERE
follow.followin_user_id = 1
ORDER BY
posts.createdtime DESC
');

return $qry->result();
```

the result should look something like this

```
    +---------+-------------+-----------------------------+-----------+---------------------+---------+------------------+------+--------+
| post_id | title       | description                 | createdby | createdtime         | user_id | followin_user_id | date | status |
+---------+-------------+-----------------------------+-----------+---------------------+---------+------------------+------+--------+
|       5 | yeah2       | hithere for the 2nd time    |         3 | 2015-07-18 01:40:05 |       3 |                1 | NULL | NULL   |
|       4 | yeah        | hi there                    |         3 | 2015-07-18 01:37:48 |       3 |                1 | NULL | NULL   |
|       2 | hello again | its night now               |         2 | 2015-07-18 01:06:23 |       2 |                1 | NULL | NULL   |
|       1 | hello       | the sun is shiningtoday lol |         2 | 2015-07-18 01:05:46 |       2 |                1 | NULL | NULL   |
+---------+-------------+-----------------------------+-----------+---------------------+---------+------------------+------+--------+
4 rows in set
```

now all you have to do is to get the 1st row where user_id (createdby) changes with PHP something like this

```
$user_id_flag=NULL;
foreach ($result as $row)
{
if($user_id_flag != $row->createdby)
    echo  $row->title;
else
    $user_id_flag=$row->createdby;
}
```

this will show you the last post title of each user following the user with the id = 1

hope that inspire you

cheers!